# AES_encrypt/AES_decrypt only returns part of a message

Tags: openssl, java-native-interface

I don't know why the following code will return  "Hello native! Th" not "Hello native! This is from jni load!\n", may someone tip it?

```
#include "helloJNI.h"
#include "openssl/aes.h"

#define LEN 1024

jstring jni_text(JNIEnv *env, jclass clz)
{
    AES_KEY aesKey;
    int result;
    const char origin[] = "Hello native! This is from jni load!\n";
    char out[LEN];
    char outout[LEN];
    memset(out, '\0', sizeof(out));
    memset(outout, '\0', sizeof(outout));
    result = AES_set_encrypt_key((const unsigned char *)"abc123", 256, &aesKey);
    LOGE("encypt key result %d\n", result); /* is 0 */
    AES_encrypt((const unsigned char *)origin, (unsigned char *)out, &aesKey);
    LOGE("after encrypt, chars is %s\n", out);
    result = AES_set_decrypt_key((const unsigned char *)"abc123", 256, &aesKey);
    LOGE("decrypt key result %d\n", result); /* is 0 */
    AES_decrypt(out, outout, &aesKey);
    LOGE("after decrypt, chars is %s\n", outout);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, outout); /* return "Hello native! Th" */
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing JNI for this? It can all be done directly in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `AES_encrypt((const unsigned char *)origin, (unsigned char *)out, &aesKey);`

`AES_encrypt` operates on 16-byte blocks. 16 is the block size of AES.

Effectively, you truncated your message.

> `AES_decrypt(pout, outout, &aesKey);`

Here, you only decrypted 16 byes. The remainder of the buffer was back filled with 0. The 0 served as the ASCII-Z terminator.

---

You are effectively operating the cipher in ECB mode. ECB mode is probably the wrong mode for your needs. ECB mode is only secure if one message is encrypted under one key. Otherwise, the attacker learns the same message was encrypted twice.

Additionally, its only secure *if* the message is smaller than the block size. If the message is larger than the block size, then ECB mode can leak information.

---

You should probably use CBC mode. You should also use the `EVP_*` functions instead rather than `AES_encrypt` and `AES_decrypt`. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

If you are only encrypting the data, then you lack integrity and authenticity assurances. So the cipher text is malleable, which is usually a bad thing. In this case, it would be better to use a mode like EAX, CCM or GCM. For that, see [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption).

Comment: Thanks, I'm newer, the information is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Each call to AES_encrypt encrypts one AES block...16 bytes. That's why, with a single call, you're ending up with precisely 16 characters in your encrypted buffer.