# AES decryption only works for first 16 characters

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm trying to get a simple AES encrypt/decrypt going using c++ for my computer science class.  It works almost perfectly, but the decryption will only work on the first 16 characters of the character array.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "openssl/aes.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned char teext[] = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";

    /*created keys for en- and de-cryption*/
    unsigned char key[] = "abcdefghijklmnop";
    unsigned char iv[] = "abcdefghijklmnop";

    /*char array for encryption and decryption output*/
    unsigned char enc_out[80];
    unsigned char dec_out[80];

    /*creating key variables*/
    AES_KEY enc_key, dec_key;

    /*encryption process*/
    AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &enc_key);
    AES_encrypt(teext, enc_out, &enc_key);

    /*decryption process*/
    AES_set_decrypt_key(iv, 128, &dec_key);
    AES_decrypt(enc_out, dec_out, &dec_key);

    cout << "AES encryption"
         << "Encrypted: " << enc_out << endl 
         << "Decrypted: " << dec_out << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling with this:

```
 g++ Crypto.cc -L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o crypto
```

The program will encrypt **"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"** just fine.  But when decrypting it outputs **"The quick brown"** and t**hen random characters**.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AES\_encrypt/AES\_decrypt only returns part of a message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837830/aes-encrypt-aes-decrypt-only-returns-part-of-a-message). Use the `EVP_*` interfaces as instructed in the cited duplicate. Don't use `AES_encrypt` and `AES_decrypt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AES_decrypt` just decrypts one block of 16 bytes of AES data. I believe it is a lower level function than what you want.

You're much better off using the `EVP_*` level functions instead. You can find a pretty complete example of how to use these on the openssl wiki - it's even using AES ecryption : https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption

Comment: If you are doing a comp-sci class, then you might want to look at setting up your own wrappers to use the low level AES_* functions to develop your own high level encryption modes.  Start with ECB mode, then CBC and CTR modes.  That will give you a better understanding of how block cyphers work.  CTR mode also helps understand stream cyphers as well.  See [Block Cipher Modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)